# Resizable Imageview Android

Tags: java, android, resize

I am trying to make an app that allows people the resize the image view or perhaps the bitmap just like those in microsoft office. How should I layout my views so that I can put the a resizing button on the 4 corners of my imageview?

Comment: Not to disappoint you, but that is going to be a bit more complicated than it seems. It's not just a matter of resizing an ImageView, it's primarily a matter of your user interface. I think this question is a bit too vague in terms of context for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @AeroDroid I was actually asking how can I write my XML file, so that the buttons can be located at the four corners accordingly.

Comment: In that case, I would advise you to use http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/5/ tutorial. I think a RelativeLayout would be the better way to go with this.